# Using a JSON service as a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, model

How can I use a JSON service as a model for a Rails 3.2 application?

I would like to link model methods to JSON requests, e.g.

- `MyModel.create` to generate a JSON request to create a new record
- `MyModel.find` to generate a JSON request to retrieve a record and decode the JSON response into a model object

What is the preferred way to build this type of functionality? One option that I am looking at is to create a custom [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) adapter.

Thanks.

**Update:**
Note that I can't use ActiveResource because this requires the JSON service to respond in a certain way, which it doesn't in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: it depends on your JSON service.

Is the service RESTful, for starters? If so, you're in luck. ActiveResource is [dead](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f1637bf2bb00490203503fbd943b73406e043d1d), so I wouldn't advise using it, but the code itself would provide a good starting point for creating a set of wrapper methods like `create` and `find` to access your API and manipulate records the way ActiveRecord creates and queries records in the DB. That's relatively easy if your API is RESTful because [rails is built around RESTful-ness](http://css.dzone.com/news/rest-with-rails-part-1), so the mapping between the two becomes much cleaner.

[This article](http://css.dzone.com/news/rest-with-rails-part-iii-using) sums it up well:

> Rails makes it extremely easy to build Web services that follow the REST principles and work equally well with Web browsers and the programmable Web. In fact, a lot of that simplicity comes directly from following these principles. We didn’t have to tell our client how to create, read, update or delete the resource, those all followed from using the proper HTTP methods. All we had to do is point our client at the right place.

If your service is *not* RESTful, which judging from the comments on other questions I think is perhaps the case, then you'll have your work cut out for you. ActiveModel will not do this work for you: `create` is defined in [ActiveRecord::Persistence](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb), and `find` is defined in [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb).
They're not in ActiveModel. ActiveResource is able to reproduce them fairly easily because it makes assumptions about the type of service it is interfacing with (i.e. that it is RESTful, plus a few other things).

What ActiveModel offers is all the other stuff that makes rails so useful for dealing with models: its validation system, serialization methods, dirty tracking of attribute changes,
callbacks (`before_save`, `after_save`, etc.), translation/localization, and so on. These are all very useful functions to have, but they still leave you with the problem of wrapping your API calls.

So here's what I would recommend, based on my albeit limited experience (see my final note about that):

1. First, take a close look at your API and figure out how close it is to being RESTful. If it is *not* RESTful, you'll have to think about how to work around this so you can treat it like a RESTful service. A good reference on how to do this is O'Reilly's [RESTful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do) (specifically Chapter 2, "Writing Web Service Clients".)
2. Create an API wrapper around it that implements `create`, `find` and whatever other ActiveRecord-like functionality you want to have. You'll probably want to use a gem like
   [Faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/) for actually making requests to the API rather than working directly with Net::HTTP. (I've never used DataMapper so can't comment on that.)
3. Include whatever elements of ActiveModel you want to use to make your wrapper class more like a rails model: validations, serialization etc. In Rails 4, you can actually include everything using the new barebones [ActiveModel::Model](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/03/barebone-models-to-use-with-actionpack-in-rails-4-0/).

That will get you much of the way to using your JSON service as a Rails model.

For the record, my experience in actually implementing this kind of thing is limited to building an API wrapper (in the works) for accessing an XML API. The wrapper has a class which includes ActiveModel validators for validating queries to the API. I've found the ActiveModel validators really useful for guaranteeing that the API is accessed correctly, but the wrapper is only for getting records from the API, not for actually creating or updating them, so the interface is quite a lot easier than what I expect you'll be building.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. Fortunately, the JSON service is RESTful, it's just that it doesn't respond in the manner expected by ActiveResource. I will avoid ActiveResource now that I know it is dead, and will instead read the DZone article that you have linked to. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh that's good news! In that case, the task shouldn't be too difficult. Even though you're not using ActiveResource you might try having a look at the code to see how it works.

Comment: In case you're still working on this, a few other gems which might be helpful: https://github.com/filtersquad/api_smith https://github.com/remiprev/her https://github.com/apotonick/roar

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `ActiveResource`, you can use it instead of `ActiveRecord` to work with a RESTful JSON API see [this link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) and [this (apidock)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this seems to require that the JSON API responds in a certain way, which the one I'm working with doesn't. For example, it responds with `OK` if a new record is created, rather than a JSON representation of the new record.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to implement an ActiveModel. This [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) covers the basics.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that. What is the advantage of ActiveModel over DataMapper?

Comment: ActiveModel is included with Rails, so you get better support for it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I do just this in my gem "[otrs_connector](http://github.com/cpuguy83/otrs_connector)"... It won't work for your service but it can give you an idea on how to do it... The approach I took may not be the best and needs to be refactored a bit, but it does work, and pretty well at that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

If the webservice is outside of the normal "Rails way" of doing things, I would recommend [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/). It is pretty easy to make a [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to the webservice that responds however you want it to.

For instance, here is their example of accessing the Twitter timeline

```
class Twitter
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'twitter.com'

  def initialize(u, p)
    @auth = {:username => u, :password => p}
  end

  # which can be :friends, :user or :public
  # options[:query] can be things like since, since_id, count, etc.
  def timeline(which=:friends, options={})
    options.merge!({:basic_auth => @auth})
    self.class.get("/statuses/#{which}_timeline.json", options)
  end

  def post(text)
    options = { :query => {:status => text}, :basic_auth => @auth }
    self.class.post('/statuses/update.json', options)
  end
end

twitter = Twitter.new(config['email'], config['password'])
pp twitter.timeline
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting alternative, but I would prefer for the JSON service to function like a traditional Rails model.